# What's the best way to handle default values for contrucctor-injected dependencies?

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I'm fairly new to dependency injection and was wondering about how to handle default values. Let's say for example I have a class that expects 5 interfaced dependencies when constructed, but for each of those there is a default if null. This leads to a potential

`new Thing(null, null, null, null, $dep);`

with several `$this->thing = $thing ?: new DefaultThing();` in the constructor.

There has to be a better way. Is this a problem that a DI container would solve? I've been looking at League\Container but it wasn't clear how I would do that.

Comment: If you want to work with a list of objects that were instantiated with some preset parameters, you should use "Factory method" or/and "Factory class" patterns. If those preset parameters OR objects, created by factories, should be related to (depend on) other classes, then you can use DI on top of that. For example in your factory method implementation you can get access to dependencies through the service locator.

Comment: http://www.jamesshore.com/Blog/Dependency-Injection-Demystified.html  You can stop reading after "the really short version". I'm pretty sure you're confused about DI